# Ошибка выхода из спящего режима

Tags: bios, материнская-плата

Иногда когда пытаюсь выйти из спящего режима, компьютер не включается и вентиляторы начинают работать на все 100% (как я понял это сбой материнки)
Думаю что это связано с биосом, bios последней версии
материнка стоит Asus PRIME B560M-K
Напишите что можно сделать